# Can't use many2many field in attrs?

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

I got problem while using many2many in attrs, it's fine with domain but got error while using in attrs. Do we have any solution or workaround for this issue?

```
<field name="visible_fields" widget="many2many_tags"/>
<field name="create_uid" attrs="{'invisible': [('id','not in', visible_fields or False)]}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the 'or operation' inside the right branch can be parsed. I would try something like this:

```
<field name="create_uid" attrs="{'invisible': ['|',('id','not in', visible_fields), ('id','=',False)]}"/>
```

Comment: it's not working even without or likes this

attrs="{'invisible': [('id','not in', visible_fields)]}"

Comment: this page might help you: https://www.odoo.com/es_ES/forum/ayuda-1/which-operators-are-available-for-attrs-in-a-view-26244